# how i can pass data from coutroller to view in zend famwork

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I used zendframwork, this is my code in `controller`

```
      $getRows = $this->MgGeneral->select();
            foreach($getRows as $value) {
                var_dump($value);
            }
```

i want send `$getRow` to `view` but it's in object (array in array), so what i need pass to `view` true is `$value` that i var_dump it's show

[image]

So how i can pass `$value` to `view` ?

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, just pass the value to:

```
$this->view->yourVariable = $yourValue;
```

In your view, you can access the value like this:

```
var_dump($this->yourVariable); /* you'll get $yourValue */
```

Bring to your code:

```
$getRows = $this->MgGeneral->select();
foreach($getRows as $value) {
    $this->view->value[] = $value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Harry

by your answer now i get correct by

```
    $passtoview = array();
    $getRows = $this->MgGeneral->select();
    foreach($getRows as $value) {
           $passtoview[] = $value;
    };
    var_dump($passtoview);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller do:

```
$this->view->value = $value;
```

and in the view you can get it by doing:

```
$this->value;
```

Comment: it's in simple case for process code structure,  it's not my case

Comment: Well, you can do $this->view->rows = $getRows; and then do the loop in the view.